# How to mock a Builder using Junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am having a builder in Java whose initialization is inside a method as follows.

```
public void doSomething() {
    SymphonyClient client = new SymphonyClient.Builder("", password, uname, "");
    client.postMessage(message);
}
```

Now when writing unit test cases, how do I mock the SymphonyClient object.

Answer (score 1):

You can not mock `SymphonyClient` as it is right now, you have 3 options here

1. Make `SymphonyClient` a instance field and inject throw constructor into unit tested class.
2. Create package private method `getSymphonyClient` and mock method using mockito Spy.
3. Create a mock service which provide a valid http response for you client call.

Additional if builder is part of your base code you can create `setTestInstance` method and used for unit testing, as you do not want to make it public you can make it package private and provide access to it only for testing classes by creating a `SymphonyClientTestAccess` in test folder.

Comment: Option 4: use PowerMock(ito) instead, Option 5: use JMockit instead - as they allow mocking calls to new. But I agree, options 1 to 3 to be preferred.